# Get Json and Convert it in to a List [Groovy]

Tags: groovy

I am using Groovy to get a list of docker images from our artifactory,

I was able to get the list of version for a specific docker image as a json and I would like to put it in a list so I will be able to use it as an "active choice parameter".

I am not a groovy expert but I tried to create a small script but I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
```

**This is my script:**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = ["curl", "-X", "GET", "https://stg.jfrog.io/XXX/api/storage/docker-local/genie/galerts?uri", "-H", "Postman-Token: 26403513-778c-43c8-b44b-70cb2bbc4352", "-H", "X-JFrog-Art-Api:Pqs", "-H", "cache-control: no-cache"].execute().text
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(response)
String idValue = parsedJson.children.uri
newString = idValue.replaceAll("[<>\\[\\]//]", "");
//def output = [newString]
def l = newString.split(',').collect{it as int}
```

**The Full Json that I am getting back is:**

```
{
    "repo": "docker-local",
    "path": "/genie/galerts",
    "children": [
        {
            "uri": "/1.0-SNAPSHOT",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.1",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.1-76",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.1-SNAPSHOT",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.2",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.3",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.4",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.4.1",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.4.2",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.4.2-Release",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.4.3",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.4.3.1",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/1.4.4",
            "folder": true
        },
        {
            "uri": "/_uploads",
            "folder": true
        }
    ],
    "uri": "https://stg.jfrog.io/XXX/api/storage/docker-local/genie/galerts"
```

**And this is the result I get after manipulations:**

Result: 1.0-SNAPSHOT, 1.1, 1.1-76, 1.1-SNAPSHOT, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2-Release, 1.4.3, 1.4.3.1, 1.4.4, _uploads

All I need is to get this result into a list, So I will get separate values from that list (as you can see in the image I uploaded  -this is how it looks like now)

[image]

Comment: The error is clear - `"1.0-SNAPSHOT"` is not an `int`. Just use: `def l = newString.split(',')` with `collect { it as int }`.

Comment: 1.4.1 isn't an int either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...

```
String idValue = parsedJson.children.uri // THIS IS A LIST, which you're then converting to a string by assigning it to one.
```

instead:

```
List versions = parsedJson.children.uri
```

or, if you prefer:

```
List versions = parsedJson.children.collect { it.uri[1..-1] }  // strips off the leading "/"
```